# How to store php array in jquery variable?

Tags: jquery

Is it posible to store php array in jquery variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

You can `json_encode` your array in PHP and then use it with jQuery via a `getJSON` request.

See: http://php.net/json_encode and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

you can either use a json request or store the variable on a hidden fiel on page load and read it with jquery